# React native reanimated - change animation params with props

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

i am using react native reanimated.
I cant change animation value passing different props to component.
This is my expo code : [expo code](https://snack.expo.io/@cklinx/reanimated-props-change)

Actually i want change the `min` variable inside my `snappable.js` components to `props.minValue` so i can change the animation dynamically.

```
const min = props.minDist ? props.minDist : 0
```

The first time the component gets the prop but after it seems not change anymore.

Here how i pass the prop to Snappable component.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Snappable minValue={this.state.min}/>
    <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.touch}
    onPress={() => this.setState({min: 0})}>
    <Text>Change Props</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little all over the place. First off, you're not setting your state correctly. You're using a function based component but attempting to use `this.setState()`. This method does exist in a functional component. If you want to use state in a functional component, you need to use the `useState` hook.

Second, it doesn't look like you do anything with the `minValue` prop in your `Snappable` component. You're passing a `minValue` prop into the component but you don't utilise it.

**Edit (add hooks example):**

You can set your state with hooks like so:

```
export default function App() {
    const [min, setMin] = React.useState(200)

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Snappable minValue={min} />
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.touch}
            onPress={() => setMin(0)}>
            <Text>Change Props</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going correct the second part and the function based component. Can you help me with the first one (useState)? Actually i dont know how do it.

Comment: Of course, no problem at all. I'll update my answer appropriately :)

Comment: I changed my code. The props seems not work, can you check please?